# Why does Tab Bar Controller turn ViewController into View?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I am creating a simple iOS app. I started with a Tab Bar Controller. I added a UIViewController. I control click linked the Tab Bar Controller to the new ViewController (and picked segue: view controller.) From what I can tell, this turned my ViewController into a View in the Tab Bar. With a ViewController I know how to pull up the code editor and go to work. As a View, I can't find a way to pull up the code editor and start working on the button action I placed in this new  View/ViewController. Sorry this is such a newbie Tab Bar question...

Comment: what a view? Segue is always from VC to VC.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. When you click on the items in the 'explorer' in the left pane, the tab controller has 3 'scenes' and each scene contains a view, not a viewcontroller.

Comment: don't get it. Show your screen.

Comment: I apologize. This was a very beginner mistake. I needed to create a swift file (of type Cocoa), save it to the project, then declare that new swift file as the Class in the Custom Class attribute of the ViewController. (Also I found the ViewController could be grabbed by clicking on the title bar of the View in the storyboard.) I hope this helps anyone else searching/having this problem.